# weka Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15 at weka.core.DenseInstance.value double pred = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i))

Tags: java, exception, weka

I have an Exception in my program 
I am using weka in netbeans and I get my training and testing data from Mysql 
I dont have any problem in my connection as well my attribute's names and position is the same in both taining and testing.

I searched alot regading this Exception and i didn't find any suatible solution for this case :(

Help me PLZ.

This is my code:

```
public class RandomForestModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
        query.setUsername("root");
        query.setPassword("");
        query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM dataset.dataset");
        Instances inst = query.retrieveInstances();
        inst.setClassIndex(inst.numAttributes() - 1);

        RandomForest tree = new RandomForest(); // new instance of tree
        tree.buildClassifier(inst); // build classifier

        // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(inst);
        eval.crossValidateModel(tree, inst, 10, new Random(1)); // Cross-validation
        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));

        /* Gets Testdata from DB */

        InstanceQuery Test = new InstanceQuery();
        // Test.setDatabaseURL("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dataset");
        Test.setUsername("root");
        Test.setPassword("");
        Test.setQuery("SELECT HaveAutisticChild FROM dataset.testingdata"); // Read
                                                                            // table
        Instances unlabeled = Test.retrieveInstances(); // into data
        // set class attribute
        unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);

        // create copy
        Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);
        // label instances
        for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
            double pred = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
            labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(pred);

            // print class label
            System.out.println(pred + " -> "
                    + unlabeled.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
        }

    }
}
```

---

I got this Error in line 117 :(

```
ll7:      double pred = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
```

---

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
    at weka.core.DenseInstance.value(DenseInstance.java:347)
    at weka.core.AbstractInstance.isMissing(AbstractInstance.java:319)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree$Tree.distributionForInstance(RandomTree.java:950)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.distributionForInstance(RandomTree.java:728)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.distributionForInstance(Bagging.java:814)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:173)
    at RandomForestModel.main(RandomForestModel.java:117)
```

---

This is my data in arff file , but I am using Mysql version of the same data
Training

```
@relation LastVerData

@attribute MAgeAtConception {Young,Middle_aged,Senior}
@attribute FAgeAtConception {Young,Senior,Middle_aged}
@attribute MOccupationalStatus {House-wife,Employee,Retired}
@attribute MNatureOfWorking {None,Exposed-to-chemicals,Exposed-to-radiation}
@attribute KinshipBetweenCouples {No-relationship,Distant-relative,First-Cousin}
@attribute FamilyHousingNear {None,Main-street,Chemical-Factory,Plastic-Factory,Oil-Refinery}
@attribute FSmoking {Non-smoker,Shisha,Smokes,Electronic-cigarettes,Hasheesh,Shammah}
@attribute FHealthStatus {Healthy,Obesity,Food_Allergies,Kidney_problems,Epilepsy,Hypertension,Asthma,Heart_problems,Diabetes,Arthritis,Liver_problems,Migraine,Anemia,Lupus}
@attribute MHealthStatus {Anemia,Obesity,Healthy,Asthma,Liver_problems,Heart_problems,Epilepsy,Food_Allergies,Hypertension,Migraine,Diabetes,Kidney_problems,Arthritis}
@attribute HaveLanguageDelayChild {No,Yes}
@attribute HaveOveractiveChild {No,Yes}
@attribute HaveDistractedChild {No,Yes}
@attribute PlanningforPregnancy {Yes,No}
@attribute UseNaturHerbsBefPreg {No,Indian-Installment,Marjoram,Cumin,Rashad,Rosemary,Miramiah,Khawajoa,Madina-Herb,Green-tea,Yansoon,Cinnamon,Shammar,Helbah,Mint,Saffron,ladys-mantle,Zaatar,Amlaj,Murr,Herbs-Weight-Loss,Chamomile}
@attribute MVaccinBefPreg {No,Measles,Seasonal_Flu,Hepatitis_B_virus,Needle-bombing-egg,Hajj_Vaccination,Corticosterone,Tetanus}
@attribute TakeMedicineBefPreg {No,Anemia-Therapy,Thyroxine,Antidepressants,F,Psychological-Therapies,Contraceptive,Antibiotic,Diabetes_Therapy,Fertilization,PCOS,Painkiller,Dostinex,Aspirin,Colon_Therapy,Asthma-Therapy,Duphaston,Regulate-Menstruation,C_V-D,'Cod- liver-oil',Cypro-Vita,Hormonal-Therapy-Progesterone,Vaginitis-Therapy,Anti-inflammatory,Hair-Vitamins,Roaccutane,Triple-Fat-Therapy,Cholesterol,Antipyretic,Breast-feeding-Therapy,Gestagens}
@attribute PregCondition {Normal,By_dope_pregnancy,After_frequent_miscarriages,IVF,Artificial_Iinsemination}
@attribute ShortPI {Yes,No}
@attribute MSmokedDurPreg {Non-Smoker,Smokes,Shisha}
@attribute MEmotionalStatusDurPreg {Regular,Happiness,Unhappiness}
@attribute AvgUseMobilDurPreg {More-than-Four-hour,Half-to-hour,Less-than-Half-hour,Two-to-four-hour,one-to-Two-hour}
@attribute MHealttStatusDurPreg {Healthy,Iron_Deficiency,Intestinal_Catarrh,Seasonal_flu,Dryness,Herpes,'Eye virus',Skin_Allergy,Infections_in_urine,Allergy,Chickenpox,Bacteria_in_blood,Kidney_Problems,Peptic_Ulcer,Facial_Palsy,Hepatitis,Cholecystitis,'Hard breathing',Anemia,Tonsillitis,Average_Bleeding,Diabetes_Pregnancy,Pus_in_the_urine,'Deficiencies_in_the _placenta',Appendix,Colon,Hypertension,Albumin,Meningitis}
@attribute UseNaturHerbDurPreg {No,Miramiah,Marjoram,Green-tea,Murr,Cumin,Yansoon,Chamomile,Angelica,Mint,Cinnamon,Shammar,Zaatar,Helbah,Rashad,Rosemary}
@attribute TakeSuppDurPreg {F,None,V-D,F_C,I,C_I,F_I,Pregrancy-multivitamin,C,Vitamin-C,F_C_I_V-D,F_C_I,'Cod- liver-oil',F_C_V-D,F_I_V-D,F_V-D,I_V-D}
@attribute TakeMedicDurPreg {No,Thyroxine,Revitalization,Antibiotic,Gestagens,Painkiller,Antipyretic,Antihistamine,Corticosterone,Hypertension,Diabetes_therapy,Aspirin,Gallstones_therapy,Chickenpox_Therapy,Anemia-Therapy,Contraceptive,Epilepsy_Therapy,Abdominal_Colic_Therapy,Colon_Therapy,Progesterone,Antibiotic_Vaginitis,Flu_Therapy,Fizzing_Vaginitis,Antiacide,Regulate_Menstruation,Asthma_Therapy,Drop_Nasal_Congestion,Diabetes_Therapy,Swine_Flu_Therapy,Blood-thinners,Anti-inflammatory,Constipation_Therapy,Appendix_Therapy,Acidity_Therapy,Anti-congestionandAllergies,catch-cold_Therapy,Dostinex}
@attribute MVaccinDurPreg {No,Seasonal_Flu,Hajj_Vaccination,Measles,Tetanus,Oxygen_needle_for_fetus,Fetus_food_deliveries_needle,Needle_for_prevention_of_poisoning,Corticosterone,Gestagens,AB_negative_blood,Needle_for_deformation_of_fetus_intestines,Meningitis,For_Complete_fetal_lung,Hepatitis}
@attribute AccidentDurPreg {No,Falling,Sliding,Car_Accident,Hitting}
@attribute BirthTime {On_Time,Postponed_labor,Premature_birth}
@attribute ObstructedLabour {No,Yes}
@attribute DeliveryMethod {Natural_Childbirth,Natural_Childbirth_with_induce_labour_Intravenously,'Cesarean section','Natural_Childbirth_with_induce_labour_Vaginal suppositories'}
@attribute PeriodOfBF {BottleOnly,'Less_than_3 _Month',6_to_12_Month,3_to_6_Month,12_to_18_Month,18_to_24_Month,36_Month}
@attribute HaveAutisticChild {No,Yes}

@data
Young,Young,House-wife,None,...............,Yes
```

Testing

```
@relation TestingData

@attribute MAgeAtConception {Young,Middle_aged}
@attribute FAgeAtConception {Young,Middle_aged}
@attribute MOccupationalStatus {House-wife,Employee}
@attribute MNatureOfWorking {None}
@attribute KinshipBetweenCouples {Distant-relative,First-Cousin,No-relationship}
@attribute FamilyHousingNear {None,Main-street}
@attribute FSmoking {Non-smoker,Smokes,Shisha,Haseesh}
@attribute FHealthStatus {Healthy,Epilepsy,Obesity,Asthma,Hypertension,Food_Allergies}
@attribute MHealthStatus {Healthy,Obesity,Anemia,Arthritis,Epilepsy,Hypertension}
@attribute HaveLanguageDelayChild {No,Yes}
@attribute HaveOveractiveChild {Yes,No}
@attribute HaveDistractedChild {No,Yes}
@attribute PlanningforPregnancy {No,Yes}
@attribute UseNaturHerbsBefPreg {No,Miramah}
@attribute MVaccinBefPreg {No,Seasonal_Flu}
@attribute TakeMedicineBefPreg {No,Fertilization,Psoriasis_Therapy,Arthritis_Therapy}
@attribute PregCondition {Normal,By_dope_pregnancy}
@attribute ShortPI {No,Yes}
@attribute MSmokedDurPreg {Non-smoker,Smokes}
@attribute MEmotionalStatusDurPreg {Happiness,Unhappiness,Regular}
@attribute AvgUseMobilDurPreg {Less-than-Half-hour,Half-to-hour,one-to-Two-hour,Two-to-four-hour,More-than-Four-hour}
@attribute MHealttStatusDurPreg {Healthy,Seasonal_Flu,Instestinal_Catarrh}
@attribute UseNaturHerbDurPreg {No}
@attribute TakeSuppDurPreg {None,F,F_I,F_I_V-D,I,F_V-D}
@attribute TakeMedicDurPreg {No,Painkiller,Diclofenac,Gestagens,Insulin}
@attribute MVaccinDurPreg {No,Tetanus}
@attribute AccidentDurPreg {No,Falling}
@attribute BirthTime {On_Time,Postponed_labor,Premature_birth}
@attribute ObstructedLabour {No,Yes}
@attribute DeliveryMethod {Natural_Childbirth,Natural_Childbirth_with_induce_labour_Intravenously,'Natural_Childbirth_with_induce_labour_Vaginal suppositories','Cesarean section'}
@attribute PeriodOfBF {3_to_6_Month,'Less_than_3 _Month',12_to_18_Month,BottleOnly,18_to_24_Month,6_to_12_Month}
@attribute HaveAutisticChild {Yes, No}

@data
Young,....,?
```

Testing Data from Mysql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDZZ5.png)

Another question ,How I defined the class in testing data from Mysql ?
In arff I think its  easer ! 
the attribute and its value are exist at the end of the file like this

```
@attribute HaveAutisticChild {Yes, No}
```

@asettouf said: Didn't you forgot to add tree.buildClassifier(unlabeled);

I added this statment and get the error changed to Exception in thread "main" `weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree: Cannot handle unary class!`

Comment: Paste implementation of `classifyInstance` method.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that whatever the `classIndex` is, it's in the last position in `Instances`?

Comment: it is method in weka see link pls
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html#classifyInstance-weka.core.Instance-

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  Yes I know that it is a class

Comment: Didn't you forgot to add `tree.buildClassifier(unlabeled);` ? Otherwise can you provide a sample of your data to test?

Comment: @asettouf I add this statment now and the error changed to

Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree: Cannot handle unary class!

Comment: @asettouf Sorry, how i can attach a picture to show you my data ?

Comment: What I could imagine (not being an expert in any way) is that the sample data used to build the classifier, and the testing data have somehow different format, it could help if you could put a sample of your dataset.dataset, and from dataset.testingdata (hopefully not a picture as monkeys have a hard time copy and pasting data from it)

Comment: @asettouf Can I edit my Qestion to put a screenshot from both data ?

Comment: Sure, why could you not edit to add more information?

Comment: @asettouf Good, I alterd my quetion and add sample of data m waiting your comment :)

Comment: I changed sql statment for testing data to "SELECT  *  FROM dataset.testingdata" and the error changed as well Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging.distributionForInstance(Bagging.java:816)
 at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:173)
 at RandomForestModel.main(RandomForestModel.java:132)